# Creating a Php array from an exploded string

Tags: php

I have a string.

```
$string = "this is my string";
```

So I want to explode it.

```
$explode = explode(' ', $string);
```

Now I want to know if it's possible to insert each word into an array so I can get this.

```
$array = array('this', 'is', 'my', 'string');
```

Comment: the `$explode` is the array similar to `$array`. The `explode` function already did it.

Comment: That is exactly what you have in `$explode`, what is the problem?!

Comment: With `explode()` you *already* have desired array ( `$array` = `$explode` )

Comment: Thanks very much Frayne

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE So there is no question here?!

Comment: I think so, Hey!! Is there any question??

Comment: You can always use `var_dump($my_var)` ou `print_r($my_var)` to see what is in your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like [Frayne Konok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5234224/frayne-konok) said, the `$explode` is the array similar to `$array`. The explode function already did it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
$string = "this is my string";
$explode = explode(' ', $string);

for ($i=0; $i<count($explode); $i++) {
    array_push($array, $explode[$i]);
}
print_r ($array);
```